# Swift UI Collection View - How to display "segued" user input into Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Im pretty new to programming, and I'm building my first app (budgeting app).

Im using a Collection view to display 3 specific figures on a Users Profile. I have a snippet of the code that i put together so far after watching a tutorial on Collection Views. The problem is, here they use an "items" array to build a calendar app with 31 dates inside the cell. However, id like to display information gathered from a user's previous input, that has been calculated to display a few specific figures - such as (You saved $_ this week / You're on track to save $_ this month). Im passing the calculations through a newUser object, which stores all their data & the necessary functions needed to display these numbers. My question is- how would i go about getting that information displayed into the cells i have set up. Please and thank you for any help!

This is the ViewController class where i implemented the code for the collection View. I have also created a model class- UserInfo where i have stored the necessary calculations and initializers needed to create the newUser object - which gets initialized on a screen directly before, that segues into this "User Profile" info.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

```
let items = ["1", "2", "3","4","5"]

var customerName : String?
var payCheckOne : Double?
var payCheckTwo : Double?
var monthlyEarning : Double?
var desiredSavingsAmount : Double?
var budgetForEachDay : Double?


@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var payCheck1TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var payCheck2TextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var desiredSavingsTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: Int) -> Int{

    return items.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as!
    DailySavingsCollectionView

    cell.dailySavingsViewLabel.text = items[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use an alert notification or present a temporary view controller.

you would do so in the prepareforSegue method.

Comment: Hi thanks for the super quick response- if I were to present a temporary view controller, does it matter that the Collection view is only represented on the bottom half of the screen. IE- the information on top would stay constant because it isn’t part of the collection view (ie- their profile picture)

Comment: if you present a view controller, it will just show that over the top of the collection view... I suggest embedding it within a navigation controller so you can easily go between scenes.  product>embedded in>navigation controller.

Comment: You would also have to pass the info to the new VC
Within your prepareForSegue
newVC = segue.destination as! NewViewController
newVC.info = what you want to pass in

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help Jordan! You Rock!